# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a script to solve sudoku puzzles, I originally built it just for 9x9, and am now expanding it to any sudoku. The script works on 4x4 and 9x9 but when I give it a 16x16 it returns TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable python 2.7 at line 38, 'if i in dic[entry]: dic[entry].remove(i)'

heres my code

```
from math import sqrt
def sudoku(puzzle):
    n = len(puzzle)
    # Builds Dictionary with board position and value
    dic = {str(i+1) + '-' + str(j+1): puzzle[i][j] for i in xrange(0, n) for j in xrange(0, n)}
    # Builds list of each possible value for all empty (0) spaces, only considers row and column possibilities
    while 0 in dic.values():
        for entry in dic:
            if dic[entry] == 0:
                temp1 = []
                temp2 = []
                for entry1 in dic:
                    if entry1[0] == entry[0]: temp1.append(dic[entry1])
                    if entry1[-1] == entry[-1]: temp1.append(dic[entry1])
                for i in xrange(1, n+1):
                    if i not in temp1: temp2.append(i)
                dic[entry] = temp2
    # populates dictionary with invalid spaces in each square
        sqrdic = {str(i)+str(j): [] for i in xrange(1, int(sqrt(n))+1) for j in xrange(1, int(sqrt(n))+1)}
        for entry in dic:
            if len(str(dic[entry])) == 1:
                for index in xrange(1, int(n/sqrt(n)+1)):
                    if (index-1)*sqrt(n) < int(entry[0]) <= index*sqrt(n):
                        for index2 in xrange(1, int(sqrt(n))+1):
                            if (index2-1)*sqrt(n) < int(entry[-1]) <= index2*sqrt(n):
                                sqrdic[str(index) + str(index2)].append(dic[entry])
        # Removes invalid choices based on values in the square
        for entry in dic:
            if len(str(dic[entry])) > 1:  # only looking at spaces with multiple possible values
                for index in xrange(1, int(n/sqrt(n)+1)):
                    if (index-1)*sqrt(n) < int(entry[0]) <= index*sqrt(n):
                        for index2 in xrange(1, int(sqrt(n))+1):
                            if (index2-1)*sqrt(n) < int(entry[-1]) <= index2*sqrt(n):
                                for i in sqrdic[str(index)+str(index2)]:
                                    if i in dic[entry]: dic[entry].remove(i)
        # Looks for any space whose possibilities have been reduced to one and replaces the list with that value
        # All unsolved spaces are then set back to 0
        for entry in dic:
            if type(dic[entry]) is list and len(dic[entry]) == 1:
                dic[entry] = int(dic[entry][0])
            elif type(dic[entry]) is list and len(dic[entry]) > 1: dic[entry] = 0
    solution = [[dic[str(j)+"-"+str(i)] for i in xrange(1,n+1)] for j in xrange(1,n+1)]
    for line in solution: print line
```

and heres two test puzzles

```
sudoku([[1,0,0,2,3,4,0,0,12,0,6,0,0,0,7,0],
       [0,0,8,0,0,0,7,0,0,3,0,0,9,10,6,11],
       [0,12,0,0,10,0,0,1,0,13,0,11,0,0,14,0],
       [3,0,0,15,2,0,0,14,0,0,0,9,0,0,12,0],
       [13,0,0,0,8,0,0,10,0,12,2,0,1,15,0,0],
       [0,11,7,6,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,15,0,0,5,13],
       [0,0,0,10,0,5,15,0,0,4,0,8,0,0,11,0],
       [16,0,0,5,9,12,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,8,0],
       [0,2,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,0,12,5,8,0,0,3],
       [0,13,0,0,15,0,3,0,0,14,8,0,16,0,0,0],
       [5,8,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,13,9,15,0],
       [0,0,12,4,0,6,16,0,13,0,0,7,0,0,0,5],
       [0,3,0,0,12,0,0,0,6,0,0,4,11,0,0,16],
       [0,7,0,0,16,0,5,0,14,0,0,1,0,0,2,0],
       [11,1,15,9,0,0,13,0,0,2,0,0,0,14,0,0],
       [0,14,0,0,0,11,0,2,0,0,13,3,5,0,0,12]])

sudoku([[0,0,0,6,0,5,9,4,7],
      [4,7,2,8,0,9,6,1,5],
      [0,0,9,1,0,4,8,0,0],
      [1,2,4,0,5,8,0,0,0],
      [7,3,8,2,9,6,1,5,4],
      [0,0,0,3,4,1,2,7,8],
      [0,0,7,9,0,3,5,0,0],
      [5,9,1,4,0,2,7,8,3],
      [3,8,6,5,0,7,0,0,0]])
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: At first look it seems like as if you have used `in` keyword at the place of `==` keyword, This kind of mistake generally raises this type of error, But I am not sure if same case is here as well.

Comment: So when I run it, `dic[entry] = 13` when it fails (previously it has been `[]` at that line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is from this line:

```
if len(str(dic[entry])) > 1:  # only looking at spaces with multiple possible values
```

Now that you're doing larger puzzles, a double-digit number will return `True`, even though it only has a single value.

It's not clear to me why you need to convert all these things to strings.  It seems to me you can store them as lists and just check if the length of the list is greater than 1.

Otherwise, you can test whether type is list or int.

Comment: Ah! its so obvious! It's being converted to a string since the puzzle consists of both lists and integers so its converted to a string to avoid an error from calling len() on an int, kind of a choppy work around. Thank you!

Comment: so test if `type(...)==list`.  This seems to fix it, but I'm not sure how long it will take to finish...  Solving sudoku-like problems can take a very long time depending on the algorithm.

Comment: psst --- if this solves your problem, feel free to "accept" my solution ;)

Comment: Done, thank you for the reminder, I'm new here. That certainly fixed my problem, it will still not solve a 16x16 puzzle but I realized thats due to my use of calling the first and last character of the dictionary keys to grab the row and column number, this obviously doesn't work with values with more than one digit. Thanks Again!